# SQL query incorrectly returns 0 row results on varchar column with values of alpha, numbers, and dashes

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I am trying to select `accesskey` from my database however it returns 0 rows when it's actually there, I'm not sure what the problem is.

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM accesskeys WHERE accesskey="CAF-BNUNOYLQCTZHVTO";
```

Returns this:

[image: returns this]

However the accesskey is in the database:

[image: is in db]

This is the structure of the database:

[image: structure]

I have no idea what is the problem, I also receive no errors in phpmyadmin other than the empty result.

Does anyone perhaps knows the issue?

Comment: Try `TRIM()`.  Could be whitespace.  `SELECT * FROM accesskeys WHERE TRIM(accesskey)="CAF-BNUNOYLQCTZHVTO";`

Comment: Does the value in the database happen to have spaces around it?  Are you sure your "O"  chars shouldn't be zeroes? (Or vice-versa.)

Comment: `TRIM()` did not work and there are no whitespaces or grammatical problems.

Comment: Oh, there are like 20 different UTF8 dashes, use the wrong one, no good results.  Try this `SELECT * FROM accesskeys WHERE accesskey RLIKE "BNUNOYLQCTZHVTO";`

Comment: However, when I add a brand new accesskey to the database and run the query on that it returns it which is why I'm confused.

Comment: Thanks, the RLIKE method works however is there a way to do this without using RLIKE? Like is there a way to change the encoding, etc?

Comment: It's not necessarily the encoding.  Think of HTML entities, `&endash;`, `&emdash;`, there's long dash, short dash, dotted dash, thin dash, thinner dash, etc..  These are all different characters, sometimes you need a magnifying glass to differentiate them.  You should update the row using its ID and the right dash symbol.  If that works, I can post it as answer?

Comment: Sure, go ahead. Will something like this work though:
`ALTER TABLE accesskeys CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET UTF8; `? Or even changing it manually?

Comment: I added an answer below.  You're not going to be able to fix it with changing the character set, remember, long-dash and short-dash are different characters, the way that A and B are different characters.  A charset conversion will not help.  You'll want to rewrite the values using the correct form of dash that you want.  Hopefully my answer helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common problems with selecting not matching when it should...

- Check for whitespace, or run the query with `TRIM()`.
- Check your O's if they're 0's.
- Check your dashes.  There are many types of dashes.

In a console, where every character is forced to be the same size, it's virtually impossible to see the difference between these two commands...

```
UPDATE accesskeys SET accesskey = "CAF–BNUNOYLQCTZHVTO" WHERE id = 2;

UPDATE accesskeys SET accesskey = "CAF—BNUNOYLQCTZHVTO" WHERE id = 2;
```

Yet the difference is that the first one has an `&ndash;`, the second one has an `&mdash;`.  The ideal solution here is to update the record to reflect the actual dash mark that you're using.  You can know that this is the case if this command works...

```
SELECT * FROM accesskeys WHERE accesskey RLIKE "BNUNOYLQCTZHVTO";
```